# Visual studio auto add parentheses to function name

Tags: c++, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

Is there an option or a (free) extension in VS2015 (for C++), such that when Intellisense auto-completes a function name (at the call site), it also adds opening and closing parentheses and sets the cursor in between them?

Comment: Ever found one?

Comment: @notanalien: Unfortunately not, but I don't remember if I ever did a throughout search after I posted this question here.

Answer (score -4):

I believe this functionality is built into Visual Studio 2015.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting

There you will find multiple items that you can tweak to your exact preferences.

Comment: I haven't found it there, but I'll give it another look.

Comment: I sem to be unable to find the appropriate option (or combination thereof) could you be more specific or was this just a guess?